# Shift/reduce conflict in yacc-Flex

Tags: c, flex-lexer, yacc, lexer

I have following grammar in yacc, however i get 1 shift/reduce conflict:

```
   %union {
   char* integer;
    char* string;
    char* boolean;
    char* date;
};



%token <integer> INTEGER
%token <string> STRING
%token <boolean> BOOLEAN
%token <date> DATE
%token WORKBOOK_START WORKBOOK_END STYLES_START STYLES_END STYLE_START STYLE_END WORKSHEET_START
%token WORKSHEET_END CLOSE_TAG EQUAL QUOTES COL_END_TAG
%token TABLE_START TABLE_END COLUMN_START ROW_START ROW_END CELL_START CELL_END DATA_START DATA_END
%token ID NAME PROTECTED EXPCOLCOUNT EXPROWCOUNT STYLEID HIDDEN WIDTH HEIGHT MERGEACR MERGEDOWN TYPE
%token MY_NUMBER MY_STRING MY_BOOL MY_DATETIME

%%
WORKBOOK: WORKBOOK_START INWORKBOOK WORKBOOK_END ;

INWORKBOOK: WORKSHEET MORE_WORKSHEETS 
      | NUM_STYLES WORKSHEET MORE_WORKSHEETS
      ;

MORE_WORKSHEETS: WORKSHEET MORE_WORKSHEETS
           |
           ;

NUM_STYLES: STYLES NUM_STYLES
      |
      ;

STYLES: STYLES_START INSTYLES STYLES_END ;

INSTYLES: STYLE INSTYLES
    |
    ;

STYLE: STYLE_START INSTYLE STYLE_END ;

INSTYLE: id CLOSE_TAG ; 

id: ID EQUAL QUOTES STRING QUOTES {checkID($4);};

WORKSHEET: WORKSHEET_START INWORKSHEET WORKSHEET_END  ;

INWORKSHEET: name protected CLOSE_TAG MORE_TABLES
       | protected name CLOSE_TAG MORE_TABLES
       | name CLOSE_TAG MORE_TABLES
       ;

name: NAME EQUAL QUOTES STRING QUOTES ;

%%
```

I have used `-v` option to get the generated conflicts and it seems that I have a problem in   `WORKBOOK: WORKBOOK_START INWORKBOOK WORKBOOK_END ;`

```
State 1
1 WORKBOOK: WORKBOOK_START . INWORKBOOK WORKBOOK_END
STYLES_START     shift, and go to state 3
WORKSHEET_START  shift, and go to state 4
WORKSHEET_START  [reduce using rule 7 (NUM_STYLES)]
INWORKBOOK  go to state 5
NUM_STYLES  go to state 6
STYLES      go to state 7
WORKSHEET   go to state 8
```

How can I fix this problem? Any suggestions?

Comment: Replace the rules for INWORKBOOK with `INWORKBOOK: NUM_STYLES WORKSHEET MORE_WORKSHEETS`. This should parse the same grammar, but eliminate the conflict.

Comment: Your rule `MORE_WORKSHEETS: WORKSHEET MORE_WORKSHEETS
           | /* Nothing */
           ;` is right-recursive; you should use the left-recursive rule `MORE_WORKSHEETS: MORE_WORKSHEETS WORKSHEET
           | /* Nothing */ 
           ;` — it reduces the storage space needed to process the grammar.  However, this has nothing to do with the shift/reduce conflict AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

`NUM_STYLES` can be empty. So given the two alternatives:

```
INWORKBOOK: WORKSHEET MORE_WORKSHEETS 
          | NUM_STYLES WORKSHEET MORE_WORKSHEETS
```

if the input stars with a token which could be the start of `WORKSHEET`, there is no way for the parser to tell whether it should use the first production, or whether it should reduce an empty `NUM_STYLES` and use the second production.

You should look again at the state table, and try to see how it is telling you about that problem.